# Why are shared libraries (.so files) loaded as private?

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

This is from an smaps file:

`b750d000-b76bc000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 918842     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so`

The `p` in `r-xp` indicates it is loaded as private I believe. Why is this so? Doesn't this defeat the purpose of shared libraries if a copy of each .so file is loaded into different memory addresses for different processes? What advantage does this private loading offer?